# VLC ActiveX seek bar help in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vlc

I am making a video player, using VLC ActiveX called `AxVLCPlugin21`, so want to make it real as possible. So i thought of putting a `Trackbar1` to seek through a video, with a `Label1` for the time in `0:0/0:0` format

What I know:

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
' When the timer runs the, label text will be set to the return value of the function formattime()
    With TrackBar1
        .Minimum = 0
        .Maximum = AxVLCPlugin21.input.Length
    End With
    Label1.Text = formatTime(AxVLCPlugin21.input.Time) & "/" & formatTime(AxVLCPlugin21.input.Length)
    Try
       TrackBar1.Value = AxVLCPlugin21.input.time
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    AxVLCPlugin21.input.Time = TrackBar1.Value
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
End Sub

Function formatTime(ByVal timeVal As Integer)
    Dim timeHour As Integer
    Dim timeSec As Integer
    Dim timeMin As Integer
    timeHour = Math.Round(timeVal \ 1000)
    timeSec = timeHour Mod 60
    If timeSec < 10 Then
        timeSec = "0" & timeSec
        timeHour = (timeHour - timeSec) \ 60
        timeMin = timeHour Mod 60
    End If
    If timeMin < 10 Then
        timeMin = "0" & timeMin
        timeHour = (timeHour - timeMin) \ 60
    End If
    If timeHour < 0 Then
        Return timeHour & ":" & timeMin & ":" & timeSec
    Else
        Return timeMin & ":" & timeSec
    End If
End Function
```

Code cited from [here](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/171125-track-bar-help/)

The seek bar works perfectly but the label containing the time does not, for example if the video a 5 minute and when playing the video, the time is in the 50th second the label will show `0.50/5.0`, when the video time is 2 minutes and 55 seconds it will show `0.55/5.0`.

My point is that when the video time reaches more than 60 seconds the minute resets to zero.

Is there a problem in the code? I have included some extra information like the `Trackbar1_Scroll` and `Timer1_Tick`.

And also I want the time to appear like `00:00/00.00` and the function does not have the code for hours so anyone can help me creating an hour in the function, and display the time as `00:00:00/00:00:00`

Thank you
[shannon]

Comment: [TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.frommilliseconds)

Comment: Thank You @Jimi for the help!